# Does end user need to have .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0 to run Silverlight 3 and 4 applications?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Does the end users need to have .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0 installed on their machines in order to run Silverlight 3 or 4 applications from within IE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope but he need to install the runtime of silverlight and it needs to be the same version or higher as where the app is developed in

Answer (score 0):

Plus Silverlight is backwards compatible (for the most part ;D ), so as long as they have the latest runtime they should be able to run older SL applications no problem.

Comment: yes, that is why i wrote "... the same version or higher as where the app is developed in", but thanks for the extra clear statement on this

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight don't require full .net framework use Silverlight Apps. it use a CLR that is a subset of original .net framework classes only required to run silverlight apps.
More info about required classes for Silverlight: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194%28VS.95%29.aspx

plus if you have .net Silverlight runtime 4.0 you can run any silverlight app that is built using older version of silverlight.

Regards.